# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'PSKeyword'

Tags: pdfminer

I tried this code
but a error given
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'PSKeyword'

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextBoxHorizontal

document = open('Sample.pdf', 'rb')
#Create resource manager
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
# Set parameters for analysis.
laparams = LAParams()
# Create a PDF page aggregator object.
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
for page in PDFPage.get_pages(document):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    # receive the LTPage object for the page.
    layout = device.get_result()
    for element in layout:
        if instanceof(element, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
            print(element.get_text())
```

Comment: I got the same issue :/